# iTerm Mac/ How to export/import bookmarks

Tags: macos, iterm

How can I Import/Export bookmarks in iTerm program on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 10):

For the new version of `iTerm`, the file is now

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

Comment: Note: in OS X 10.9 Mavericks, ~/Library/Preferences is cached by the operating system. If iTerm2 has been recently running before you replace the file, you will need to reboot in order for the changes to take effect. (Otherwise, the plist file would be silently reverted to the old version.)

Comment: You don't need to reboot. Just re-read the pref file with other terminal app. Check this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111534/iterm2-doesnt-read-com-googlecode-iterm2-plist

Answer (score 6):

It is not specific to just bookmarks, but if you want to migrate bookmarks and other settings, you'll want to copy the Preferences file from either:

```
~/Library/Preferences/iTerm.plist
~/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.iTerm.plist
```

from an existing setup/account to:

```
~/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.iTerm.plist
```

iTerm.plist is the old location and is used by certain versions of iTerm. The new location is net.sourceforge.iTerm.plist.

Comment: You should use Terminal to overwrite the plist file, if you do it from iTerm, it will save it back when you quit and nothing will change.